# Xcode 12 - Error when building .m file because of " Could not build module 'std' "

Tags: c++, xcode, vtk

I'm facing a problem I wasn't able to resolve in days.

I want to include some VTK header within my .m file, which works up to the point where some further linked VTK-Headers within the one I included tries to do:

```
#include <fstream>
```

An error occurs saying

> 'fstream' file not found

After some googling I came across the solution to add the following to my 'Header Search Paths':
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/include/c++/v1/"

The file now seems to be found, but some new errors occurred.

> Could not build module 'std'
>
> Unknown typename 'namespace'
>
> Unknown typename '_LIBCPP_BEGIN_NAMESPACE_STD'
>
> Unknown typename '_LIBCPP_END_NAMESPACE_STD'
>
> Expected ';' after top level declarator
>
> etc.

These occur whithin __nullptr, cstddef, type_traits.

I also tried to change the "C++ Standard Library" from 'Compiler Default' to 'libc++' or 'libstdc++', but nothing worked.

Does anybody know how to resolve this?

Additional Information:

- macOS Big Sur 11.2.3
- Xcode 12.4
- arm64 architecture

Comment: You should not have to modify the library search paths if you created your project correctly, but you can only include C++ headers in an Objective-C++ file (suffix ".mm"), not in Objective-C.

Comment: As @molbdnilo suggests, rename your `.m` file into `.mm` to use Objective-C++ dialect.

Comment: Thanks, that resolved my issue! Sorry I'm new to Objective-C(++) and still struggling